# What is event name function of which is triggered before a page/structure group is saved?

Tags: sdl-tridion, event-system

I want to know what is the event function name in which [[ Event gets triggered when **BEFORE** page or structure group is saved. ]]

Comment: You are being downvoted because this question doesn't show what you tried so far. I would recommend some research, maybe starting here: https://docs.rws.com/816112/725603/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/event-handlers

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that you should be punished for the question, especially if you are new to the Tridion SE. However, it is always helpful to give more explanation to the problem you are trying to solve. From what I think you are trying to achieve it trigger ES before save. For that you can use different event phases. In your case, I guess you can use ***Initiated*** phase, as per the following documentation:

https://docs.rws.com/816112/102986/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/event-phases

**Initiated**

**The event handler is triggered just before the actual event. For example, just before saving a Component, you can trigger code that analyzes its contents, derives a set of Keywords, and adds these Keywords to the metadata of the Component.**

Comment: I agree - we should be helping new people, not punishing them. Thanks for the positive reply Marko